# Cobas c311 not reading bar-code

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

I am developing a Java machine integration system to communicate with medical machines.

I have a problem reading `code-128` bar-codes on a particular machine (Cobas c311), knowing that the same bar-code is working all other scanners and machines. I am using `birt` to generate these barcodes. I have tried to edit the font manually to make the bars longer and shorter with no effective result. I tried to use code-`code-39`as well, changed the bar-code printer and labels and still having the same issue.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same problem with Cobas C311 machine, the problem was in the label type where we were using Matte labels, changing the label ribbon types to a glossy label type have solved the problem. Also make sure to use hugh quality ink and high quality printer since the barcode scanner in Cobas C311 is very sensitive